# Change and define code by sheets names with vba code

Tags: excel, vba, file, rename

Currently I have this code below:

```
 Sub EXCELS()

'Create excel files

 Dim i As Integer
 Dim name_file As String
 For i = 5 To Sheets.Count
 name_file = Sheets(i).Name

 Worksheets(i).Copy

 With ActiveWorkbook
 .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\marya\OneDrive - Desktop\Cantina\listas" & "\" & 
 name_file & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
 .Close SaveChanges:=False
 End With
 Next i

 End Sub
```

I would like to change and define this code below by sheets names, as "Lista_AA", "Lista_BB". Instead of creating excel files from sheet 5, create excel files that contain the names "Lista_AA", "Lista_BB"...

```
For i = 5 To Sheets.Count
```

Error: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how we know which sheets should be exported to their own workbooks.  This answer assumes that you want to export each sheet that has a name starting with "Lista_", so that would export "Lista_AA", "Lista_BB" but not "Meal_Register"

```
Sub EXCELS()
    'Create excel files
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim name_file As String
    
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        name_file = Sheets(i).Name
        If Left(name_file, 6) = "Lista_" Then
            Worksheets(i).Copy
            
            With ActiveWorkbook
                .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\marya\OneDrive - Desktop\Cantina\listas\" & _
                name_file & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

If there is a different pattern for the sheet names, or if you want to specify a list of sheet names to export, please make a comment below and I'll amend or make a new answer.

Comment: Thanks @Gove! What should I change in your code so that instead of saving it replaces the file? Since a file may already exist in that folder

Comment: just add the following before the For...Next loop: Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Comment: Can you please adjust?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that will overwrite existing workbooks with the same name without prompting the user

```
Sub EXCELS()
    'Create excel files
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim name_file As String
    Dim file_path as String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        name_file = Sheets(i).Name
        If Left(name_file, 6) = "Lista_" Then
            Worksheets(i).Copy
            file_path = "C:\Users\marya\OneDrive - Desktop\Cantina\listas\" & name_file & ".xlsx"

            ' try to delete a file that has the same name as the one we are about to save  
            on error resume next
            kill file_path
            on error goto 0     

            debug.print file_path
            With ActiveWorkbook
                .SaveAs Filename:=file_path, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I really don't understand... This error appears sometimes: "Method 'SaveAs' of object'_Workbook' failed"

Comment: I've updated the code to print the full path of the file name you are trying to save.  Run this version and report back what is printed in the immediate window.  Press ctrl+g to open the immediate window

Comment: still giving error in the same place...

Comment: yes.  what did it print to the immediate window?

Comment: I added the print above, please check

Comment: One possibility is to delete the excel files (xlsx) that are in the folder and that start with "List_" and then save the files

Comment: The code in this answer is printing information that will help us understand the answer to  the "immediate window".  You need to understand how to access this very important debugging tool for me to be able to help you.  Please review this link to learn about it  https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/vba-immediate-window-excel/ Then report back what this code prints to the immediate window

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243456/discussion-between-gove-and-marya).

Comment: I added code to try to delete a file of the same name before saving the new one, but I'm doubtful if it will solve the problem